# solaris 10..no virtual consoles?

Tags: solaris, console, virtual-consoles

I refuse to think solaris 10 no virtual consoles
I did

```
svcadm enable svc:/system/console-login:default
```

nothing happen,no virtual consoles,service remain offline
and no error is given
if i start the script of this smf service give me this command

```
/usr/lib/saf/ttymon -g -d /dev/console -l console -m ldterm,ttcompat -h -p solaris10.blu.privata console login:
```

and on console i see..no output

of course solaris10.blu.privata is reachable by ping.
So..no virtual consoles?Or there is other way?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.  Are you not getting *any* console?  What are you expecting?

Comment: Simply a virtual console like linux,bsd,ctrl+alt+f4 give me console4 f5 give console5 etc..actualy I cannot see any console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solaris 10 does not have virtual consoles. The were not introduced to Solaris until Solaris 11.

The major customers for Solaris tend to be large-scale enterprises, where the ability to use virtual consoles isn't needed as much as it is for desktop systems.